# Loading Data onto Couchbase

Tags: macos, couchbase

Hi i'm trying to load data onto couchbase following the instructions of one of their user manuals. My knowledge of IT is absolutely terrible and some of the instructions look like it's written in another language.

### The instructions state

1. Open a terminal, and navigate to the Couchbase bin  in folder for your system.

### 2.Mac OSX/Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase­core/bin/

When i tried copying 2. into the Mac terminal i get the following

/Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase­core/bin/
-bash: /Applications/Couchbase: No such file or directory

I then looked back at the instructions which says

---

### Note, you may wish to add this folder to your operating system PATH statement, so that its commands may be invoked from any location. If needed, see your operating system documentation for specific details on this process.

I honestly have no idea what this means. What folder am i meant to be adding and where how do i add this? Is there any explanation in 'baby' steps which explains how to get this working? I'd really appreciate any help, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You're using something called the bash shell.  Simply speaking, a command shell (bash is just one of many) reads in lines from the user (i.e. what you type in), interprets them, figures out what programs to run from what you type, and runs them.  [This link](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/unixintro.html) might help explain further.

To make the Couchbase commands easily accessible through bash, type

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Couchbase\ Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin/"
```

After that (in the same shell window) you can just use all the Couchbase Server commands (like cbdockloader) directly by typing in the command name.  This is what they mean by "...its commands may be invoked from any location."

Read about shells and the bash shell in particular to understand how they uses paths.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i typed that into the terminal and it's saying with regards to cbdocloader command not found. Any ideas?

Comment: There are two likely reasons that might happen.  Either the path on your machine is different, or you don't have Couchbase Server installed.  Unfortunately it's hard to distinguish which is the case.  If you're sure you've installed Couchbase, try this.  Either use Spotlight and search for Couchbase Server.app, or enter into bash `find /Applications ~ -name Couchbase\ Server.app`.  The second method may take some time to finish.  If it finds Couchbase it will show the path to it.